# Node element not in instance tree

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to hide some elements of a model using the Forge viewer API, but I can't access some of them because their dbIds aren't found in the model instance tree.

It's very strange because I can't hide them using the context menu either, in the properties panel it shows undefined in the name, and it's also not found in the model browser panel.

Any ideas about how can I find those elements and show or hide them programmatically?

In the model that has this problem, those objects are curtain wall profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In the SVF format it's common to have dbIDs without any visual representation. There might be different reasons for that but the one that's most common IMHO is instancing - you can have one object as a "template" (with no geometry), and a couple of objects (with geometries) that are "instances" of that template, inheriting its properties. That is also why the dbIDs of these "template" objects are not found in the model hierarchy.

Comment: A problem is that I can't find those objects with graphical representation by iterating the instance tree.  How can I get their dbIds programmatically?

Comment: That is strange. Every object that has some graphical representation *should* be in the instance tree. Could you perhaps share a sample file (and the element you're trying to hide) with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`?

Comment: We would not share the file with anyone outside of Autodesk.